# CasperJs on Centos server How to use php to pass variables to casper js

Tags: php, phantomjs, casperjs

Okay so i have a casperjs script which does a specific task for me then echoes a result back to me.

i normally use the command

```
Casperjs script.js "variable1" "variable2"
```

after a few moments it will echo a results saying either

```
True
```

or

```
False
```

how can i use php on my server instead of using the command line 
i would like the php script to execute the command above and then echo the result back to me on my php page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP's **[shell_exec](https://www.php.net/shell_exec)** which uses php to call your command, like so:

**.php**

```
$casperjs = "casperjs";
$script = "script.js";
$arg0 = $variable1; 
$arg1 = $variable2;
$command = "$casperjs $script $arg0 $arg1";
$result = shell_exec($command);
echo $result;
```

**script.js**

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var arg0 = casper.cli.get(0);
var arg1 = casper.cli.get(1);
casper.start('http://example.com/', function() {
  if (this.getTitle() == 'blahblah') {
    this.echo('True');
  } else {
    this.echo('False');
  }
});     
casper.run();
```